# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: replay.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock paper scissors game. When you win or lose, a victory or defeat screen appears.  I want it so that when you click "replay", it takes you back to the homepage. However, when the victory or defeat screen appears, the error occurs. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
// Variables
const homepage = document.getElementById("homepage");
const gamepage = document.getElementById("gamepage");
const victoryScreen = document.getElementById("victory-screen");
const defeatScreen = document.getElementById("defeat-screen");

const firstToInput = document.getElementById("first-to-input");
const firstTo = document.getElementById("first-to");

const userNameInput = document.getElementById("username-input");
const userName = document.getElementById("username");
const cpuNameInput = document.getElementById("cpu-name-input");
const cpuName = document.getElementById("cpu-name");

const userScore = document.getElementById("user-score");
const cpuScore = document.getElementById("cpu-score");

const options = document.getElementsByClassName(".options");
const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
const paper = document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors = document.getElementById("scissors");

const cpuMessage = document.getElementById("cpu-message");
const resultMessage = document.getElementById("result");

const play = document.getElementById("play");
const replay = document.getElementsByClassName("replay");

// Shows username and CPU name at top of gamepage
function names() {
    if (userNameInput.value === "") {
        userNameInput.value = "You";
    };
    if (cpuNameInput.value === "") {
        cpuNameInput.value = "CPU";
    };
    userName.textContent = userNameInput.value;
    cpuName.textContent = cpuNameInput.value;
}

// Randomly generates CPU choice
function getCpuChoice() {
    const cpuChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    cpuMessage.textContent = `${cpuName.textContent} chose ${cpuChoice[random]}`;
    return cpuChoice[random];
}

// Adds score to user and displays win message
function winRound() {
    userScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Win!"
}

// Adds score to CPU and dislays loss message
function loseRound() {
    cpuScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Lose!"
}

// Displays tie message
function tieRound() {
    resultMessage.textContent = "Tie!"
}

// Determines winner
function result(userChoice) {

    const cpuSelection = getCpuChoice();
    switch (`${userChoice}-${cpuSelection}`) {
        case "rock-scissors":
        case "paper-rock":
        case "scissors-paper":
            winRound();
            break;
        case "rock-paper":
        case "paper-scissors":
        case "scissors-rock":
            loseRound();
            break;
        case "rock-rock":
        case "paper-paper":
        case "scissors-scissors":
            tieRound();
            break;
    }
    checkScore();
}

// Main game loop
function gameLoop() {
    /*
    // Adds border color when clicked
    options.forEach(i => {
        i.addEventListener("click", () => {
            options.forEach(j => j.style.border = "solid 4px white;");
            i.style.border = "none"
            console.log("test")
        })
    })
    */
    // Defines user choice
    rock.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("rock");
    })
    paper.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("paper");
    })
    scissors.addEventListener("click", () => {
        result("scissors");
    })
}

// Checks if someone has won
function checkScore() {
    if (userScore.textContent == firstToInput.value) {
        gamepage.style.display = "none";
        victoryScreen.style.display = "block";
        restart();
    }
    if (cpuScore.textContent == firstToInput.value) {
        gamepage.style.display = "none";
        defeatScreen.style.display = "block";
        restart();
    }
}

// Starts game
play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Forces user to select how many wins are needed
    if (firstToInput.value === "") {
        play.textContent = 'Play - Please Select "First To" Number' 
    } else {
        // Moves from homepage to gamepage
        homepage.style.display = "none";
        gamepage.style.display = "block";

        // Displays how many wins you need
        firstTo.textContent = `First to ${firstToInput.value}`;

        names();
        gameLoop();
    }
})

function restart() {
    replay.addEventListener("click", () => {
        victoryScreen.style.display = "none";
        defeatScreen.style.display = "none";
        homepage.style.display = "block";  
    });
}
```

```css
#gamepage {
  display: none;
}

#victory-screen {
  display: none;
}

#defeat-screen {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Homepage -->
    <div id="homepage">
        <h1 id="homepage-title">ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS</h1>
        <div>
            <img class="icons" src="images/rock.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-rock">Hand Rock icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="rock icon">
            <img class="icons" src="images/paper.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-paper">Hand Paper icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="paper icon">
            <img class="icons" src="images/scissors.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-scissors">Hand Scissors icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="scissors icon">
        </div>
        <label id="first-to-input-label" for="first-to-input">First to...</label>
        <br>
        <input id="first-to-input" type="number" min="1">
        <br>
        <input id="username-input" class="names" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
        <input id="cpu-name-input" class="names" type="text" placeholder="Enter CPU Name">
        <br>
        <button id="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Gamepage -->
    <div id="gamepage">
        <h2 id="first-to"></h2>
        <h2 id="names-scores">
            <span id="username"></span>
            -
            <span id="user-score">0</span>
            :
            <span id="cpu-score">0</span>
            -
            <span id="cpu-name"></span>
        </h2>
        <h1 id="gamepage-title">SELECT AN OPTION</h1>
        <div id="options">
            <img id="rock" class="options" src="images/rock.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-rock">Hand Rock icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="rock icon">
            <img id="paper" class="options" src="images/paper.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-paper">Hand Paper icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="paper icon">
            <img id="scissors" class="options" src="images/scissors.png" title='&lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com/icons/set/hand-scissors">Hand Scissors icon&lt;/a> icon by &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://icons8.com">Icons8&lt;/a>' alt="scissors icon">
        </div>
        <button id="shoot">Shoot!</button>
        <h3 id="cpu-message"></h3>
        <h3 id="result"></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Victory Screen -->
    <div id="victory-screen">
        <h1 id="victory-message">VICTORY</h1>
        <button class="replay">Replay</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Defeat Screen -->
    <div id="defeat-screen">
        <h1 id="defeat-message">DEFEAT</h1>
        <button class="replay">Replay</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move everything within an `onload` event, or even `DOMContentLoaded`, and you should be good ... if you search for DOM nodes before these are created, you won't find these, hence ID or not, the result is null

Comment: `document.getElementById("replay")` You don't have an element with `id` `replay`. Hence it returns `null`.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Read this to see what Andrea is talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

I needed to loop through each restart button because there are 2 in the class.

```
function restart() {
    for (let button of replay) {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            victoryScreen.style.display = "none";
            defeatScreen.style.display = "none";
            homepage.style.display = "block";  
        });
    }
}
```